# vim syntax highlighting for mysql general and slow query logs

Tags: mysql, syntax, syntax-highlighting, vim

I've scoured Github and vim.org for syntax highlighting for MySQL log files.  Specifically for slow-query logs, but I've come up empty handed.  I've used the `mysqldumpslow` command to make grok'ing these logs less painful, but some syntax highlighting in Vim would be ideal.

Syntax highlighting for `mysqldumpslow` would also work.  I looked into creating my own syntax file, perhaps this would be a good project to learn from.

I don't know if it matters, but my workstation is running OSX Lon and mvim.

Answer (score 4):

I usually just force the issue locally by issueing

```
:se ft=sql
```

(add `:syntax on` if you don't have it in your .vimrc)

Now, see `:help modeline` for ways to set this from the logfile itself, or `:he autocmd` for ways to make this happen on loading files with specific extensions (or names)

Comment: Thanks, that helps for reading the SQL portion of the logfile, but it doesn't really help much for the rest of it.